# Calculate the difference between the value in different rows and columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Please help me in solving the below query.
Suppose if I have a table name as Data with 3 rows: Date1, Date2 and visit window. I need to calculate Visit window value. It should be the difference of (n+1)th row of date 1 and nth row of date2. For ex: Difference of 2nd row value of Date1 and 1st row of date2 value divided by 7. Please help.

```
Table: Data
------------
Date1           Date2           VW
13-DEC-2011     15-DEC-2011     ?   
18-DEC-2011     16-DEC-2011     ?
21-DEC-2011     24-DEC-2011     ?
```

Thanks

Comment: What DBMS do you use? Do you have a primary key of some sorts in your table? What is the data type of Date1 and Date2? How do you know what row is the first row? Is it the row with the lowest value in Date1?

Comment: We use Oracle 11g, Data type is Date.
It can have primary keys and can have lesser date also in date1. I just need a sample query to retrieve the values for Visit window. It is just a puzzle not yet implemented.

Comment: You should have a look at `lead` function. It is used to access the data from the next row so you can use that value and calculate the difference between the current row and the next row.

Comment: we need to know what is the ordering criteria. Oracle does not guarantee the order of rows, so you need to specify an ordering criteria. It is the Date1 row?

Comment: Yes it should get calculated from Date1 row and It should display the Visit window value for all the 3 rows.

Comment: can you explain the "divided by 7" part? Why you divide days by 7? (Difference between two dates is expressed in days)

Comment: No I just need it to be compared with another row. Can u pl help me

Comment: ok, i'll update my answer in just few minutes

Answer (score 4):

```
select
  Date1, 
  Date2,
  lead(Date1) over (order by Date1) next_date1,
  ((lead(Date1) over (order by Date1)) - Date2)/7 as Diff
From DATA_TABLE
```

For the last row you won't get any VW, because there is no n+1 Date1.

`lead(column)` function returns value for the `column` parameter from the next row as specified in  the `over` clause.

You can find examples and other similar functions [here](http://orafaq.com/node/55).

**UPDATE** (response to a question comment - how to compare with another column)

```
select 
  Date1,
  Date2,
  Diff,
  another_column,
  CASE 
    when Diff < another_column then 'it is lower'
    when Diff > another_column then 'it is higher'
    when Diff = another_column then 'are equal'
  END as comparation,
  CASE
    when round(diff -another_column,3) = 0 then 'almost equal'
    else 'definitely not equal'
  END as rounded_comparation
from(
    select
      Date1, 
      Date2,
      lead(Date1) over (order by Date1) next_date1,
      ((lead(Date1) over (order by Date1)) - Date2)/7 as Diff,
      another_column
    From DATA_TABLE
)
```

Comment: How can I add divided by 7 part to this. Will it retrieve values for all the rows in the table. One more query, can u pl explain how Lead function works in this case. Yes the last row should not retrieve any values because of the condition. Thanks very much.

Comment: I have updated my answer; added a column next_date1 to see how it works.

Comment: if this aswer perfectly to your question you can mark the answer as 'Accepted'