# Calculate the Difference Between Numbers in Different Columns in Different Rows using Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I'm having a little trouble. I need to calculate the difference between some values that are stored in different columns and in different rows in an Access 2013 database. What I need to do is identify on a report if there are any gaps between the "Metered After" column of one row and the "Metered Before" column of the next row. I thought I might be able to do this in the query, but the example shown in this [so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664651/calculate-the-difference-between-the-value-in-different-rows-and-columns) uses the 'lead' function which I have not been able to get to work in Access 2013. Can this be done in an Access query or is it better left to VBA? An example of the report is shown below.

[image: Report Snip]

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this in a query.

If the above table is named Tab it will be something like this

```
SELECT Tab1.* 
, TabBefore.[Metered Before]
, Tab1. TabBefore.[Metered After] - TabBefore.[Metered Before] AS Diff
FROM Tab AS Tab1
     LEFT JOIN Tab AS TabBefore
            ON Tab1.[Vehicle number] = TabBefore.[Vehicle number]
```

Hopefully this will make sense and you can take it from here.

Comment: Thanks Harvey, I will git this a try.